# My php script is not using given username/pass/host rather using root@localhost (password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, connection

Got a problem! Though I found almost similar threads but none helped :(

I've written a php script to fetch the number of registered users from my MySQL database. The script is working great in my localhost; it is using the given username,pass and host name which are "root", "root", and "localhost" respectively, but the script is not using the given username/pass/host rather using root@localhost (password: NO) in Live server.

In the Live server I created a MySQL user, set an different password, and hostname there is of course not localhost. I updated the script with my newly created mysql users data. BUT, whenever I run the script, I see that the script is still using "root", "root", and "localhost"!!

take a look at the script:

```
    //database connection
    $conn = mysql_connect( "mysql.examplehost.com", "myusername", "mypass" );
$db = mysql_select_db ("regdb",$conn); //Oops, actually it was written this way in the script. I misstyped it previously. now edited as it is in the script.

    //Query to fetch data
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regd ");            
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)): 
$total_regd = $row['total_regd'];
endwhile;   

echo $total_regd;
```

-- Some says to change the default username and pass in the config.ini.php file located in phpMyAdmin directory. Would this help?? I didn't try this because either my hosting provider didn't give me privilege to access that directory (because I am using free hosting for testing scripts) or I simply didn't find it :(

Please help....

Comment: OT: **Use of `mysql_*` extension is discouraged.** Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: Thank you very much Alvin Wong for the valuable information :) Which one you recommend between MySQLi or PDO_MySQL? Which one is easier to learn and use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foreword: The MySQL extension is marked as deprecated, better use mysqli or [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo)

---

Though you store the connection resource in $conn you're not using it in your call to mysql_query() and you're not checking the return value of mysql_connect(), i.e. if the connection fails for some reason mysql_query() "is free" to establish a new default connection.

```
<?php
//database connection
$conn = mysql_connect( "mysql.examplehost.com", "myusername", "mypass" );
if ( !$conn ) {
    die(mysql_error()); // or a more sophisticated error handling....
}

$db = mysql_select_db ("regdb", $conn);
if ( !$db ) {
    die(mysql_error($conn)); // or a more sophisticated error handling....
}

//Query to fetch data
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regd ", $conn);
if (!$query) {
    die(mysql_error($conn)); // or a more sophisticated error handling....
}

while ( false!=($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) ): 
    $total_regd = $row['total_regd'];
endwhile;   

echo $total_regd;
```

---

edit: It looks like you're processing only one row.
Either move the `echo` line into the while-loop or (if you really only want one record) better say so in the sql statement and get rid of the loop, e.g.

```
// Query to fetch data
// make it "easier" for the MySQL server by limiting the result set to one record
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regd LIMIT 1", $conn);
if (!$query) {
    die(mysql_error($conn)); // or a more sophisticated error handling....
}

// fetch data and output
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
if ( !$row ) {
    echo 'no record found';
}
else {
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['total_regd']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot VolkerK for your response :) I got two questions: Q1. If MySQL extension is marked as deprecated, why still it works in my scripts? Q2. Does "LIMIT 1" mean MySQL will only query the first row?

Comment: A1: Deprecated doesn't mean "removed/deleted", it's just a note that a) you shouldn't use it for various reasons and b) it might be removed in future releases. see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php A2: Yes...ish, LIMIT 1 allows MySQL to end the operation as soon as it (definitively) has one record in the result set, in case of a `SELECT * foo LIMIT 1`, yes that would be the "first" row though you can't be sure what "first" means in this context, take e.g. `SELECT x FROM foo WHERE y>5 ORDER BY y DESC LIMIT 1`, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

What is your mysql_error()? :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply BlackCat. It was saying Access denied for user "root@localhost" (Using password: NO)